# jQuery error append child of null

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have a jQuery timer which seems to be working fine in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3FNmt/). However the same code on my wordpress site gives me an **error in the console :**

```
'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null'.
```

Can't seem to figure out why i am getting this error?

```
var target_date = new Date('12/08/2014').getTime();

// variables for time units
var days, hours, minutes, seconds;

// get tag element
var countdown = document.getElementById("ribboncountdown");
var days_span = document.createElement("SPAN");
days_span.className = 'days';
countdown.appendChild(days_span);

// update the tag with id "countdown" every 1 second
setInterval(function() {

    // find the amount of "seconds" between now and target
    var current_date = new Date().getTime();
    var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;

    // do some time calculations
    days = parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
    seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;


    // format countdown string + set tag value.
    if (days < 0) {
        days_span.innerHTML = '<span>' + days * -1 + '</span>' + ' days since';
    } else {
        days_span.innerHTML = '<span>' + days + '</span>' + ' days to go';
    }



    //ribboncountdown.innerHTML = days + "d,;  

}, 1000);
```

Comment: I can't see any jquery in your code, just plain javascript.

Comment: This would only happen if there wasn't an element with the id 'ribboncountdown'.

What do you see in console when adding the following after the countdown declaration line:

    console.dir(countdown);

Comment: Do you have an element with id `ribboncountdown`

Comment: Yes this elements only shows if user is logged in. The element does not show if user is logged in

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your code in $( document ).ready(function() { in order to get the dom ready before your js gets fired.

so the code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {    
var target_date = new Date('12/08/2014').getTime();

// variables for time units
var days, hours, minutes, seconds;

// get tag element
var countdown = document.getElementById("ribboncountdown");
var days_span = document.createElement("SPAN");
days_span.className = 'days';
countdown.appendChild(days_span);

// update the tag with id "countdown" every 1 second
setInterval(function() {

    // find the amount of "seconds" between now and target
    var current_date = new Date().getTime();
    var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;

    // do some time calculations
    days = parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
    seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;


    // format countdown string + set tag value.
    if (days < 0) {
        days_span.innerHTML = '<span>' + days * -1 + '</span>' + ' days since';
    } else {
        days_span.innerHTML = '<span>' + days + '</span>' + ' days to go';
    }

    //ribboncountdown.innerHTML = days + "d,;  

}, 1000);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the html to show the counter was missing. Adding this html for logged out users solved the problem. Thanks for the help